# How to build SQL for get grouped data by date

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have data in Postgres DataBase like this

```
 | id |  name  |    start_date       |      end_date       |
   1    Event1  2018-09-14 14:22:00     2018-09-15 14:22:00
   2    Event2  2018-09-15 14:22:00     2018-09-15 15:22:00
```

I need SQL which return me response group_by date and If Event duration (end_date, start_date) took 2 days i need return him twice in two days array and this all should be order by date. So response should look like this.

```
{
  "2018-09-14": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Event1",
        "start_date": "2018-09-14 14:22:00",
        "end_date": "2018-09-15 14:22:00",
    }],
    "2018-09-15": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Event1",
        "start_date": "2018-09-14 14:22:00",
        "end_date": "2018-09-15 14:22:00",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Event2",
        "start_date": "2018-09-15 14:22:00",
        "end_date": "2018-09-15 15:22:00",
    }]
 }
```

Could you help me with this SQL?

Comment: "took 2 days" means: covered two dates? Because your example took only 1 day. So an event with ["2018-09-14 23:59:59", "2018-09-15 00:00:00"] should appear in two groups, right?

Comment: @yura - Can you please edit your question based on this - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=500af3b35bc2af939d79ff7a4234c25c)

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_object_agg(dates, data_array)
FROM (
    SELECT
        dates,
        jsonb_agg(data) as data_array
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            unnest(ARRAY[start_date::date, end_date::date]) as dates,
            row_to_json(events)::jsonb as data
        FROM
            events
    )s
    GROUP BY dates
) s
```

1. Convert table into json object with `row_to_json`.
2. aggregating both dates into one array with `ARRAY[]`
3. `unnest()` expands the data with every single date.

The result so far:

```
dates        data
2018-09-14   {"id": 1, "name": "Event1", "end_date": "2018-09-15 14:22:00", "start_date": "2018-09-14 14:22:00"}
2018-09-15   {"id": 1, "name": "Event1", "end_date": "2018-09-15 14:22:00", "start_date": "2018-09-14 14:22:00"}
2018-09-15   {"id": 2, "name": "Event2", "end_date": "2018-09-15 15:22:00", "start_date": "2018-09-15 14:22:00"}
2018-09-15   {"id": 2, "name": "Event2", "end_date": "2018-09-15 15:22:00", "start_date": "2018-09-15 14:22:00"}
```

4. `DISTINCT` eliminates all tied elements where `start_date == end_date`.
5. grouping by the dates, aggregating the json elements into an json array (`jsonb_agg`)
6. after all, grouping the table into json elements (`jsonb_object_agg`) with `key == date` and `value == json array`

Comment: Thx. Maybe me example is bad. I have this data in Postgres DB. like this
| id | name  |           start_date          |          end_date           |
  1  Event1    2018-09-14 14:22:00     2018-09-15 14:22:00

Comment: @YuraBysaha this made the query a little bit simpler. I changed it.

Comment: Could you help me and send SQL where i get rows not json ?

Comment: you mean instead of {id: 2, name: Event2, ...} you want columns with name id, name, etc. with values 2, Event2, ...?

Comment: Yes, i need a rows( and cant modify your script self( maybe dates can be like a field in each row and than i can group it

Answer (score 1):

If you just want rows you only need the these steps:

1. aggregating both dates into one array with `ARRAY[]`
2. `unnest()` expands the data with every single date.
3. `DISTINCT` eliminates all tied elements where `start_date == end_date`.

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    unnest(ARRAY[start_date::date, end_date::date]) as dates,
    *
FROM
    events
```

**Result**:

```
dates        id   name     start_date            end_date
2018-09-14   1    Event1   2018-09-14 14:22:00   2018-09-15 14:22:00
2018-09-15   1    Event1   2018-09-14 14:22:00   2018-09-15 14:22:00
2018-09-15   2    Event2   2018-09-15 14:22:00   2018-09-15 15:22:00
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d318967b6717448992721b82a21fd91a)

Comment: Its a magic!) Thank you a lot i add +1 for this answer too but left as correct first one!